# Exposing private variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, exploit

I have a question about javascript's protected memory. If I have a function done like this:

```
var obj = function(){
    var secret = "secret",
        super_secret = "my super secret string";   
    return {
        get_secret: function() {
            return secret;
        }()
    }
}();
```

Is it possible to get string from super_secret by any means?

I saw some exploit that used throw() and Error() to get variable out of function. However that wasn't done with closure. All input and "hunches" are very welcome. I'm planning a project where I need to be sure that there isn't any known way to extract or modify super_secret variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost no way to do this. Even if you load the data from some server that is not on the page to begin with, I can easily open firebug and start debugging to find the value. If you must have security then don't expose the data. Even encrypting the data won't help because the key would probably be somewhere in the javascript.

Maybe if you share what your problem is then we can think of a better solution. Javascript probably is not your best option here.

Edit, using the debugger you can do anything! Here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Actually that's the question, can you get the super_secret with Firebug? I dare you to try ;) At least I wasn't able to find it with Firebug or Webkit Inspector.

Comment: Yep its really easy. Put a debugger there in firebug, and then you can access all the data within the object.

Comment: Are you now talking about viewing the script that was evaluated or the object stored in memory? I'm talking about in memory. Can you tell me exactly how and what I need to do in order to debug evaluated obj to see super_secret.

Comment: Take a look at my screenshot. Using the debugger I can see exactly what is in memory.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I haven't used Firebug that much so pardon me my inexperience :) Interesting enough if you look at DOM, you can't access super_secret. So I guess these "private variables" are only private when it comes to other javascript on the page.

Comment: Yes. You can't hide anything from the javascript. I learned this the hard way. Even if you through the most safe way and encrypt everything, I can look for the key and use the same logic. Because it's all on the page. Long story short, if you don't want some one to hack it, then don't expose it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is going to end up running in a browser, someone could just view the source and copy-paste it (you did say "any means" :-).

Also, if someone can get arbitrary Javascript to run on your site, keeping a key secret is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can really do is encrypt and decrypt super_secret, server-side.  If you send unencrypted data to the client or give it the means to decrypt your data, your data is available to the client and you shouldn't rely on its being hidden.

Comment: That won't work because how are you going to decrypt it on the client side? If you are using some key, I can look for that key and decrypt the data. And if you are saying then only decrypt the data on the server, then why send it?

Comment: Well, exactly.  Sending it to the client is usually a bad idea anyway.  However, asp.net does it with the view state.  All I was saying is that the only thing you can securely do is store it on the client encrypted, and not decrypt it.